# Drop duplicates based on majority rule

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a table that looks like this:

```
A  B
1  cat
1  cat
1  dog
2  illama
2  alpaca
3  donkey
```

Using **`A`** as the key, I'd like to remove duplicates such that that dataframe becomes:

```
A  B
1  cat
3  donkey
```

**`1`** is duplicated three times, the value *`cat`* occurs the most so it is recorded. there is no majority for **`2`** so it is considered ambiguous and removed completely. **`3`** remains as it has no duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `groupby` + `pd.Series.mode`

This is a two step solution using `pd.Series.mode`:

```
# find the mode for each group
i = df.groupby('A').B.apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
# filter out groups which have more than one mode—ambiguous groups
j = i[i.groupby(level=0).transform('count') == 1].reset_index()
```

```
print(j)

   A       B
0  1     cat
1  3  donkey
```

---

## `groupby` + `<`custom func`>`

Alternatively, define a custom function that computes the mode and call it with `apply`. The filtration logic is subsumed into the function.

```
def foo(x):
    m = pd.Series.mode(x)
    if len(m) == 1: 
        return m

df.groupby('A').B.apply(foo).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()

   A       B
0  1     cat
1  3  donkey
```

Comment: Your code works for me, thank you! Is there a way to get the output as a dataframe that retains B as the column name for the values?

Comment: @AndyG Edited, take a look now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`statistics.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#statistics.mode), which raises `StatisticsError` if no unique mode exists.

```
from statistics import mode, StatisticsError

def moder(x):
    try:
        return mode(x)
    except StatisticsError:
        return None

res = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(moder)\
        .dropna().reset_index()

print(res)

   A       B
0  1     cat
1  3  donkey
```

---

**Performance benchmarking**

Although all 3 methods are suitable for your task, they have slightly difference performance.

Benchmarking results:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit jpp(df)  # 18.3 ms ± 414 µs per loop
%timeit cs1(df)  # 28.1 ms ± 558 µs per loop
%timeit cs2(df)  # 24.5 ms ± 595 µs per loop
```

Benchmarking code:

```
from statistics import mode, StatisticsError

def moder(x):
    try:
        return mode(x)
    except StatisticsError:
        return None

def foo(x):
    m = pd.Series.mode(x)
    if len(m) == 1: 
        return m

def jpp(df):
    return df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(moder)\
             .dropna().reset_index()

def cs1(df):
    i = df.groupby('A').B.apply(pd.Series.mode).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    return i[i.groupby(level=0).transform('count') == 1].reset_index()

def cs2(df):
    return df.groupby('A').B.apply(foo).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `value_counts` and `rank`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().rank(ascending=False)).eq(1)[lambda x: x].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   A level_1     B
0  1     cat  True
1  3  donkey  True
```

Using rank with method='average' as a voter to get "majority" from the results of value_count.